# rescuing errors in EventMachine::Deferrable

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am trying to figure out how to make the `EventMachine::Deferrable` callbacks not raise any exceptions. Instead of having `begin ... rescue` in every callback block, I am trying to wrap the block somehow with a method call so that the method rescues the exceptions:

```
require 'eventmachine'

def to_proc
  proc
rescue Exception => e
  puts "e=#{e}"
end

EventMachine::run {
  d = EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable.new
  f =  to_proc {raise 'error'}

  d.callback &f

  EventMachine.next_tick {d.succeed}
}
```

this does not work of course. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the statement `d.callback &f`, to_proc is called. The exception you're trying to catch down at `d.succeed` can't be caught, because we are already outside the context of your exception handling.

I'm not actually sure what error you're trying to catch. If it's an error in what you have EventMachine doing, you can create an `#errBack` to catch them. If you are really trying to catch exceptions that only happen in your callbacks, then you should probably just write the exception handlers in the callbacks (for the specific exceptions you expect!).

However, if you really want to catch all errors in all procs, you need to override call in class Proc:

```
# Note this code hasn't been tested and is only provided as an example
class Proc
  alias_method :old_call, :call
  def call(*args)
    begin
      old_call(*args)
    rescue Exception => e
      # Handle exception
    end
  end
end
```

I do not recommend this approach however